# How to use an Ionic on Codepen example?

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is the codepen link: 
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

I create a blank ionic project, and copy HTML to my index.html, CSS to my css/style.css, JS to js/app.js, and run `ionic serve`

what i got is following result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vg8Y.jpg

I wonder what i am missing?

I've tried to chang following contents in index.html also:

```
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Session timed out in the shared item/link. Please update it.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks for reminding, I've updated it.

Comment: You're seeing any errors in your console tab? My hunch would be that the `js` file path is wrong which is why you're having that.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan, thanks for replying. I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined" error in my console tab.

Comment: @IsaacLi Did you include also the `ionic.bundle.js` in to your `app.js`? If not, add this `<script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>` inside your `head` tag.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan, thanks! has some progress! but not enough, see: http://i.imgur.com/6agsm1T.jpg console has no return errors.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan, I've got it! add <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">solved my problem! thank you very much!